# Denied Contact access (Contacts framework, iOS)

Tags: ios, contacts

I am using Contacts framework.  I am having trouble enabling contacts if the user has switched it to off in the settings screen: `Settings app -> App name -> Turn Contacts off`

If a user turns off the app Contact permissions in the settings screen, is it possible to present a dialog to allow them to turn Contacts on? It seems as if access = always false.   Are we not allowed access once the user turns off Contacts via settings?

Here is my relevant code:

```
func requestForAccess(completionHandler: @escaping (_ accessGranted: Bool) -> Void) {
    let authorizationStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: CNEntityType.contacts)

    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .authorized:
        completionHandler(true)

    case .denied, .notDetermined:
        self.contactStore.requestAccess(for: CNEntityType.contacts, completionHandler: { (access, accessError) -> Void in
            if access {
                completionHandler(access)
            }
            else {
                //Access is always false
                if authorizationStatus == CNAuthorizationStatus.denied {
                    completionHandler(false)
                }
            }
        })

    default:
        completionHandler(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Requesting access only shows the system permissions prompt the first time you do it.  If the user denies access then you can show a view telling them that they need to enable it in the app settings to use whatever feature you are requesting access for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, once the user has denied access to Contacts, you'll need to direct them to the Settings app.

You can do this by displaying a `UIAlertViewController`, and opening the settings app via an `alertAction`

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```